# "As well as" or "as did"?

Tags: grammar

I have a question about the use of "as well as" and "as did". Which would fit better in the following sentence?

- When the earthquake began, at least fifteen men and women fell to the ground, ***as did*** many children playing in the park that day.

I appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Try a simpler example: _The children all sat down, as did their parents_. That is related to _The children all sat down, as their parents sat down_. The _did_ is a pro-verb, referring to _sat down_ in the first clause. You can also say _The children all sat down, as their parents did._ But _did_ can optionally be fronted to come after _as_, as it has in this example.

Comment: Which fits better depends on what meaning you want. The two mean different things: *as well as* refers to the number, *as did* to the action. You can't use *as did* if there is no action or you're referring to the object of an action (e.g. "He brought 100 crackers as well as some cheese.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this structure, there is (in general) some potential for ambiguity with "as well as":

> Five people talked to Alice, as well as Bob.

Did five people talk to Bob, or did Bob talk to Alice?

In your sentence there is little possibility of ambiguity, since it is unclear how "men and women" could fall to "many children", so either of your suggestions is fine.

By the way, the possibility of ambiguity can be eliminated by moving the [extraposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) phrase next to its parent:

> When the earthquake began, at least fifteen men and women (as well as many children playing in the park that day) fell to the ground.